# C# Console application to move files to specific directories based off of file name

Tags: c#, console-application, filepath

Sample file name: `S012311d130614t095121.14194092001`

The ninth character from the left is the date(130614) I then want to store this file in the following directory based off of the date:

```
1306/         (year-month)
  130614/     (year-month-day)
    S012311d130614t095121.14194092001
```

Comment: Get the file name, parse it, find the character you want, build the correct path, and move the file. Which part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to store this file in a folder named 130614?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
string input = Path.GetFileName(originalFile);
     //"S012311d130614t095121.14194092001";

string yearMonthDay = input.Substring(8, 6);

string yearMonth = yearMonthDay.Substring(0, 4);
Console.WriteLine(yearMonth);

string folder = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(rootFolder, yearMonth), yearMonthDay);
Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

// Write to folder
File.Copy(originalFile, Path.Combine(folder, input);
```

This will guarantee that a folder exists under `rootFolder` with `1306\130614`, and provide you the folder name of the created folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all files(filenames) in a directory with following code:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"Directory");
```

Then use for-each to get every string an that string array and check the ninth char of each string(I wont post code for that, a little work for you)

Use following code to copy your file:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(originFile, destFile, true);
```

Combine all that to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

First, an extension method to get a `DateTime` value from the file name:

```
public static class FileInfoHelpers
{
    private static Regex rxIso8601DateTimeValue = new Regex( @"\d{6,6}[Tt]\d{6,6}(\.\d+)$");
    private static readonly string[] formats = new string[]{
                                                    @"yyMMdd\tHHmmss.fffffff" ,
                                                    @"yyMMdd\THHmmss.fffffff" ,
                                                    } ;
    public static DateTime? TimestampFromName( this FileInfo fi )
    {
        DateTime? value = null ;
        Match m = rxIso8601DateTimeValue.Match( fi.Name ) ;
        if ( m.Success )
        {
            DateTime dt ;
            bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact( m.Value , formats , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , DateTimeStyles.None , out dt  ) ;
            value = success ? dt : (DateTime?)null ;
        }
        return value ;
    }
}
```

Then all you should need is something like this:

```
// establish the source and target directories
// ensuring that they both exist
DirectoryInfo source = Directory.CreateDirectory( @"C:\some\directory\with\files\to\move" ) ;
DirectoryInfo target = Directory.CreateDirectory( @"C:\repository" ) ;

// save the current working directory
string prevCwd = Environment.CurrentDirectory ;

try
{

  // make the destination root the current working directory
  Environment.CurrentDirectory = target.FullName ;

  // enumerate over the files in the source directory
  foreach ( FileInfo fi in source.EnumerateFiles() )
  {
    // parse a datetime out of the file name
    DateTime? timestamp = fi.TimestampFromName() ;

    // if we didn't find a valid datetime value in the file name, skip this file
    if ( !timestamp.HasValue ) continue ;

    // construct the relative path of the archive subdirectory        
    // and ensure that it exists
    string relativeSubdir = timestamp.Value.ToString("yyMM\\yyMMdd") ;
    DirectoryInfo subdir = target.CreateSubdirectory( relativeSubdir ) ;

    // build a relative path to the file's desired location
    // and move it there.
    string destination = Path.Combine( relativePath , fi.Name ) ;
    fi.MoveTo( destination ) ;

  }

}
finally
{
  // restore the original CWD
  Environment.CurrentDirectory = prevCwd ;
}
```

Easy!